# Create cron job using python script

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to create cronjob using python script. Equivalent to below code in shell script.

```
cat > /etc/cron.d/sendmail << 'EOF'
# start sendmail every 15 minutes in queue-mode instead of running as daemon
0,15,30,45 root /usr/sbin/sendmail –q
EOF
```

I tried below in python script

1st way :

```
f=open("/etc/cron.d/sendmail","w+")
f.write("0,15,30,45 * * * * * root /usr/lib/sendmail -q")
f.close()
```

2nd way:

```
job = cron.new(command='/usr/lib/sendmail –q')
job.minute.every(15)
```

I get the following error for both the ways of creating cronjob using python script :

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /tmp/tmpG4xkXv/__OPSWEXTRACT__/code.dir/setscript.py on line 56, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I have added below line at the top of the file as well, based on details in the error

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

What am I doing wrong in both the ways?

Comment: What is on line 56?

Comment: Line 56: f.write("0,15,30,45 * * * * * root /usr/lib/sendmail -q")